# How to print PHP results with commas between items but not at the end

Tags: php, mysql

I got it show all the online users but how would i make it for the last online user, to take off the comma at the end.
heres my code

```
                    while($online = mysql_fetch_array($usersonline)){
                    $username = $online['username'];

                    echo"<b> $username, </b>";
                    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using the implode method:

```
$usernames = [];

while($online = mysql_fetch_array($usersonline)){
  array_push($usernames, $online['username']);
}

echo implode(',', $usernames);
```

Comment: Congrats, this is clearly the least kludgy answer (even if it's not the tersest).

Answer (score 2):

Just operate on index and append *before*, not *after*, like so

```
$index = 0;
while($online = mysql_fetch_array($usersonline)) {
  $username = $online['username'];
  echo"<b> ".($index>0?',':'')." {$username}</b>";
  $index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $u = 0;
    while($online = mysql_fetch_array($usersonline))
    {
        $u++;
        if($u == 1){
            $usernames = '<b>' . $online['username'] . '</b>';
        }else{
            $usernames .= '<b>, ' . $online['username'] . '</b>';
        }
    }
```

Edit: implode would probably much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most elegant way, but this should work:

```
$users="<b>";
while($online = mysql_fetch_array($usersonline))
{
    $username = $online['username'];
    $users.="$username,";
}
rtrim($users,',');
$users.="</b>";
echo $users;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$join = '';
while($online = mysql_fetch_array($usersonline))
{
    $username = $online['username'];
    echo"<b> $join . $username </b>";
    $join = ',';
}
```

Or

```
$out = '';
while($online = mysql_fetch_array($usersonline))
{
    $username = $online['username'];
    $out .="<b> $username </b>,";
}
$out = rtrim($out,",");
echo $out;
```

OR as "tehlulz" suggested

```
$usernames = [];

while($online = mysql_fetch_array($usersonline)){
  array_push($usernames, $online['username']);
}

echo implode(',', $usernames);
```